# Flutter - FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. for release build

Tags: android, flutter, build, release

I failed to build flutter app.

I wrote in tarminal of VSCode.

`flutter build appbundle --release````

but failed.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\NAME\source\repos\NAME\work\flutter\APP_NAME\android\app\build.gradle' line: 58

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'keystoreProperties' for SigningConfig$AgpDecorated_Decorated{name=release, storeFile=null, storePassword=null, keyAlias=null, keyPassword=null, storeType=pkcs12, v1SigningEnabled=true, v2SigningEnabled=true, enableV1Signing=null, enableV2Signing=null, enableV3Signing=null, enableV4Signing=null} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.SigningConfig$AgpDecorated.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

build.gradle' line: 58 is a line starts from keyAlias...

```
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
```

I added these code at android\app\build.gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OPFi.png)

and I made android\app\key.jks

and I modified android\key.properties

```
storePassword=MYPASSWORD
keyPassword=MYPASSWORD
keyAlias=key
storeFile=key.jks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add code like this to initialize the keystoreProperties, for example below the other "def" statements at the top of the file:

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = file('/path/to/your/key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christian!
The problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved.

```
def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

////////////////////////////
// inserted here

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

////////////////////////////

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
```

This is the result.

```
PS C:\Users\APP_NAME>  flutter build appbundle --release

Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             15.3s
√ Built build\app\outputs\bundle\release\app-release.aab (17.1MB).
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).